# How to mock an import express.js supertest?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, sinon, supertest

I have some controller / route which handles a user signing up:

`controllers/user.js`

```
const User = require('../models/User');       // What I want to mock!
...
/**
 * POST /signup
 * Create a new local account.
 */
exports.postSignup = (req, res, next) => {
  ...
  const user = new User({
    email: req.body.email,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  ...
```

I want to test that `User` is called with the right args.

`test/userIntegrationTest.js`

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app.js');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const User = require('../models/User');

describe('POST /signup', () => {
  it('should create user with valid email', (done) => {
    const formdata = {email: 'te.st@gmail.com', password: 'asdf'};

    const UserMock = sinon.mock(User);      // This mock doesn't do what I want!

    request(app)
      .post('/signup')
      .send(formdata)
      .expect(200)
      .end(function(res) {
        expect(UserMock.calledOnce).to.be.true;
        expect(UserMock.calledWith(formdata));
      })
  });
});
```

I expect the `UserMock` to be called from the controller however this mock seems to only mock the `User` model imported in the `userIntegrationTest.js`.

How do I mock the `User` imported in `controllers/user.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use for this **proxyquire** lib (https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire).

Example of usage:

```
var apiCallsMock = require('./apiCallsMock');
var messageParser  = proxyquire('../messageParser', {'./apiCalls': apiCallsMock});
var app = proxyquire('../index', {'./messageParser': messageParser});
```